# simple xml attribute value get the using xslt in the html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, xpath

The XML file look like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="final.xsl"?>  
  <root>
    <child1 entity_id = "1" value= "Asia">
        <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "india">
            <child3 entity_id = "3" value = "Gujarat">
                <child5 entity_id = "5" value ="Rajkot"></child5>
            </child3>
            <child4 entity_id = "4" value = "Rajshthan">
                <child6 entity_id = "6" value = "Ajmer"></child6>
            </child4>
        </child2>
    </child1>
    </root>
```

This is my XSLT Code:-

```
<xsl:for-each select="//child2">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value" />    
</xsl:for-each>
```

this is my output:-

```
   india
```

I want this output in html file how can its possible 
Please Help me out of this

Comment: The only child element of the `Asia` element is `india`. Using what logic should it retrieve `Gujarat` and `Rajshthan`?

Comment: @JLRishe use this <xsl:if test="*"> replace with this <xsl:if test="*"> then output is Child1: asia Child2:inida Child3:Gujarat Child4:Rajshthan  now just Remove Asia and Inida :)

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Why should it output `Gujarat` and `Rajsthan` but not `india`, `Rajkot` or `Ajmer`? How is that decided? I don't understand the logic you are trying to use.

Comment: @JLRishe dear b'coz i want to click on gujarat then its display there child like rajkot its the reason...

Comment: In your question you said "I want only ASIA child element attribute value". Did you mean to say "I want only INDIA child element attribute value"? The only child element of Asia is india, NOT Gujarat or Rajshthan.

Comment: @JLRishe can u help me how to display this output in html file

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you won't clarify your question.

Comment: yes i got it that answer but now can you help me or give some idea how to display this output in to html file

Comment: wait i M edit my question

Comment: check it now can you got my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT will display the children of the item that matches the value of the `region` parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChild" match="*[@value]" use="../@value"/>

  <xsl:param name="region" select="'india'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChild', $region)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example, if the default value "india" is used, the output will be:

```
Gujarat
Rajshthan
```

If the value "Asia" is used, the output will be:

```
india
```

In order to pass a parameter into an XSLT, I think you'll need to use JavaScript in your web page to apply the XSLT instead of having it applied automatically.

Here is a page with some code showing how to apply an XSLT in JavaScript, and how to pass parameters into it:

http://www.articlejobber.com/tutorial/javascript_xslt_parameters_20060303_2.html

Comment: yes thats right and now how can this output display in html file?

Comment: You would essentially use the JavaScript in that page that I linked to. Is there a particular HTML element in your page that you want to add the result to?  Could you provide the filename of your XML file? Where is the selected value coming from?